# Flex 3 Binding problem

Tags: apache-flex, data-binding, binding, bindable

I have a custom ActionScript class:

```
package EntityClasses
{
import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;


[RemoteClass(alias="tkatva.tt.entities.CompanyInfo")]
[Bindable]
public class CompanyInfo
{
        public var companyInfoId:int;
        public var companyName:String;
        public var streetAddress:String;
        public var postNumber:String;
        public var city:String;
        public var country:String;
        public var email:String;
        public var businessIdentityCode:String;
        public var intBic:String;
        public var homepageUrl:String;
        public var lastUpdatedBy:String;
        public var lastUpdateDate:Date;
        public var version:int;
        public var settingGroupList:ArrayCollection;
        public var bankAccountList:ArrayCollection;
        public var personList:ArrayCollection;


}
}
```

And I want to bind these values to textBoxes, so that when user types information to the textBoxes it is populated in the class too. Is Flex 3 bidirectional so that marking the class with [Bindable] I can bind the values to a textbox for example?

This is my mxml file in which I try to bind the class:

```
    import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
        import EntityClasses.CompanyInfo;

        [Bindable]
        public var company:CompanyInfo;



        public  var uuid:String;

        private function init():void {
            company = new CompanyInfo();
        }

        private function getCompanyInfo():void {
            try {
                company = TtRo.getCompanyInfo(uuid);

            } catch (Exception) {

            }
        }

        private function handleClick():void {
            this.txtInfo.text = "COMPANY:" + company.companyName;


             TtRo.addCompanyInfo(company,uuid);

        }

        private function handleAdding(e:ResultEvent):void {
            var res:Boolean;
            res = e.result as Boolean;
            if (res) {
                this.txtInfo.text = "OK";
            } else {
                this.txtInfo.text = "NOTOK";
            }
        }

    ]]>
</mx:Script>
<mx:TextInput x="194" y="10" id="txtCname" text="{company.companyName}"/>
<mx:TextInput x="194" y="40" id="txtStreet" text="{company.streetAddress}"/>
<mx:TextInput x="194" y="70" id="txtPostnumber" text="{company.postNumber}"/>
<mx:TextInput x="194" y="100" id="txtCity" text="{company.city}"/>
<mx:TextInput x="194" y="130" id="txtCountry" text="{company.country}"/>
<mx:TextInput x="194" y="160" id="txtEmail" text="{company.email}"/>
<mx:TextInput x="194" y="190" id="txtBic" text="{company.businessIdentityCode}"/>
<mx:TextInput x="194" y="220" id="txtIntBic" text="{company.intBic}"/>
<mx:TextInput x="194" y="250" id="txtUrl" text="{company.homepageUrl}"/>
```

Whats wrong with this? The flex compiler shows me this kind of warnings: Data binding will not be able to detect assignments to "company".

Im new to Flex and any help would be appriciated... Thanks...

Answer (score 3):

No, Flex data binding is not bidirectional. You have to explicitly bind the `text` property of text fields back to the corresponding properties of the `company` object using [BindingUtils.bindProperty()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/binding/utils/BindingUtils.html#bindProperty())

```
private function init():void 
{
    company = new CompanyInfo();
    BindingUtils.bindProperty(company, "companyName", this ["txtCname", "text"]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using it in MXML components it might be more readable if you add the reverse binding in one place using the mx:Bindable tag

eg.

```
    <mx:Binding destination="company.companyName"   source="txtCname.text" />
    <mx:Binding destination="company.streetAddress" source="txtStreet.text" />
    ...
    etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

*Flex 3 Cookbook* has a lot of recipes for this sort of work in chapter 11.9 & ch 14

Answer (score -1):

You need to mark the variables themselves as bindable:

```
[Bindable]public var companyInfoId:int;
```

Welcome to Flex data binding, its lovely :)

Comment: -1. The `[Bindable]` metadata tag before a public class definition makes usable as the source of a binding expression all public properties that you defined as variables, and all public properties that are defined by using both a setter and a getter method. http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=databinding_8.html

Comment: Ahh didnt spot that :(

And I also assumed you could bi-directionally bind, as you can with ItemRenders directly to a textbox with { }. 

Looks like you cant!